# How do I add my own package to a GitHub workflow?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-api, github-actions, github-package-registry

I am trying to use the basic .NET Core Github workflow as shown [here](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/master/ci/dotnet-core.yml), but I am having trouble with a GitHub package I [created](https://github.com/MyLibrary-com/my-library-common). When the workflow gets to the Install Depedencies which performs a donet restore, it appears to not be able to find the package when running on my WebAPI repo [here](https://github.com/MyLibrary-com/my-library-web-api).

[image]

Do I need to explicitly reference the package somehow not just against the csproj files or something else and how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without any insights into how your project is setup, but I think you need to include a `NuGet.config` in the repository that the `dotnet restore` will see and use to find your package: https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-dotnet-cli-for-use-with-github-packages

This is because GitHub Package Registry is separate from the main NuGet feed.

Comment: Adding that has got me further. Now I am just having 403 401 issues for all of the packages. I tried using ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}} but it's not working. Any suggestions